# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10 ---.length() loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Hello guys here is my code

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= alignedSeqA.length(); i++) {


            if(alignedSeqA.charAt(i)==alignedSeqB.charAt(i)) {

                alignedSeqPenalty +="0";  
            }
            else if(alignedSeqA.charAt(i)=='-'){
                alignedSeqPenalty +="2";


            }else if(alignedSeqB.charAt(i)=='-'){

                alignedSeqPenalty +="2";

            }else if(alignedSeqA.charAt(i)!=alignedSeqB.charAt(i)){

                alignedSeqPenalty +="1";

            }

            }
```

and here is my error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at New.main(New.java:124)
```

when i changed my `alignedSeqA.length()` with an `integer` (like 7) it works just fine

i.e. --> output when i change it to 7 **20100201**

what am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't deface your questions when they have been solved... Just accept the proper answer and let them be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alignedSeqA.length(); i++) {
```

As first index is `0` and last is `alignedSeqA.length() - 1`

Comment: oh this is what happens when you eat for 16 hours how did i miss that

thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In Java (and most programming languages), arrays are *zero-based*.

```
i <= alignedSeqA.length()
```

Should be

```
i < alignedSeqA.length()
  ↑
```

Meaning that if you have an array of size `N`, the indexes will be from `0` to `N - 1` (total sum will be `N`).

To better explain it, let's take a specific example. Say `alignedSeqA` is of size 5, it looks like this:

```
  0   1   2   3   4
+-------------------+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+-------------------+
```

So if you loop until (include) the size (which is 5), you're out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
  i <= alignedSeqA.length();
     |
Remove this `=` from the for loop condition
```

It should be like this:

```
i < alignedSeqA.length();
```